# Use IF Statement to compare variable to stored date

Tags: vba, date, if-statement

I am trying to run a loop of my data that checks a number of different aspects, and if any fail, the macro deletes the row.  I have everything working except for the check of the date.  If a date in a given cell is equal to the date input initially, I want to keep the row, otherwise I want to delete it.  However I cant seem to get my date compare to work.  Any thoughts?

```
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Enter current as of date (MM/DD/YY)")

Dim dDate As Date
Dim NumberofRows As Long
Dim x As Long

With Worksheets("Transactions")
    NumberofRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To NumberofRows
        If (.Range("Q" & x).Value) = myValue.Date Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Delete
            Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
        End If
    Next x

End With
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `myValue`, not `myValue.Date`? You already have it as a date. Also yeah, you have to step backwards through the loop (`Step -1`) when deleting rows

Comment: When you are looping and deleting rows, you must loop backwards or you will end up skipping rows. That's the first issue. `For x = NumberofRows To 1 Step -1`

Comment: a bit of a pro tip: When deleting, loop from the last row to the first row or your iterator will not be what you think it'll be after deleting.

Comment: In the end, `InputBox` is never a great idea, because you never know what the user is going to type and you have to jump thru all kinds of hoops to make sure they entered what you expected. In this case I would just make a `Userform` that has a `DateTimePicker` on it and include an `OK` and `Cancel` button on it. It's really simple to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Enter current as of date (MM/DD/YY)")

If Not IsDate(myValue) Then Exit Sub

Dim dDate As Date
Dim NumberofRows As Long
Dim x As Long

With Worksheets("Transactions")
    NumberofRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = NumberofRows To 1 Step -1
        If Not .Range("Q" & x).Value = myValue Then
            .Range("Q" & x).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next x

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would include a check to make sure myValue is actually a valid date. `If Not IsDate(myValue) Then Exit Sub`

Comment: @braX Good suggestion - added

Comment: I tried this code and it isn't giving me any errors, but it isn't correctly comparing the dates.  Even when they are the same, it thinks they are different and wants to delete the row.  Any ideas why?

Comment: That's because you are actually comparing 2 strings or a string and a number that *look* like dates. It would be better to verify both values you are comparing are dates, then convert them to actual dates using `CVDate` - and then compare them.

Comment: @Jen Right - as braX said, you should probably do `Dim dDate As String` and see if that changes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all at once, instead of one at a time. This will be a little faster as well, and you do not have to step backwards.

Simply add all the rows you want to delete to a range, then delete the entire range.

```
Dim myValue As Date, retVal As String
retVal = InputBox("Enter current as of date (MM/DD/YY)")

If retVal = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    myValue = CDate(retVal)
End If

Dim dDate As Date
Dim NumberofRows As Long
Dim x As Long

With Worksheets("Transactions")
    NumberofRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
    For x = 1 To NumberofRows
        If Not .Range("Q" & x) = myValue Then
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = .Range("Q" & x)
            Else
                Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Range("Q" & x))
            End If
        End If
    Next x
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Comment: What happens if the user  presses cancel? An empty string will be returned and `CDate` will error.

Comment: What if the user enters their name? You really need an `IsDate()` in there somewhere.

Comment: @braX IMHO It should rightfully throw an error of `Type Mismatch`. If it simply `Exit Sub` then an end user who was typing **Jan 16, 2018** in the inputbox will think he's doing nothing wrong and the code is just not be working for some reason.

Comment: OP would have been better off using a Date Picker userform rather than an input box imo

Comment: Yes, that's what I explained in the main comments. :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, when I get this issue sorted I will work on switching to a date picker.  But when I tried this code, it isn't correctly comparing the dates. Even when they are the same, it thinks they are different and wants to delete the row. Any ideas why?

Comment: That's because you are actually comparing 2 strings or a string and a number that look like dates. It would be better to verify both values you are comparing are dates, then convert them to actual dates using `CVDate` - and then compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that compares using Date variables instead, and checks for Cancel being clicked. This way you know you are comparing apples to apples.

```
Sub Test()
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim dtValue As Date
Dim dtSheet As Date
myValue = InputBox("Enter current as of date (MM/DD/YY)", "Enter Date", Date)

' user cancelled
If myValue = "" Then Exit Sub

If Not IsDate(myValue) Then 
    MsgBox "That is not a date.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' user entered a valid date, so continue
dtValue = CDate(myValue)

Dim NumberofRows As Long
Dim x As Long

With Worksheets("Transactions")
    NumberofRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = NumberofRows To 1 Step -1
        If IsDate(.Range("Q" & x).Value) Then
            dtSheet = CDate(.Range("Q" & x).Value)
            If Not dtSheet = dtValue Then
                .Range("Q" & x).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "'" & .Range("Q" & x).Value & "' is not a date.", vbCritical
        End If
    Next x

End With
End Sub
```